# Declare decision structure inside of a System.out.println

Tags: java, if-statement, println

So I am working on an assignment where I have to have a print method in a constructor that displays a distance.
I also have to have three separate get methods depending on what the input is in the demo class.
My question is that I am trying to write the print method to contain a decision structure based on which get is used.
    public void prt() {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

```
    System.out.println(
        "The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
         " feet through air is " + 

            if (getSpeedInAir() > 0) {
                formatter.format(getSpeedInAir());
            }

            else if (getSpeedInWater() > 0) {
                formatter.format(getSpeedInWater());
            }

            else if (getSpeedInSteel() > 0) {
                formatter.format(getSpeedInSteel());
            }

            else "error";
    ) 
}
```

After trying to compile I am getting the following errors.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\GlaDOS\Desktop\JavaStuff>j Speed

C:\Users\GlaDOS\Desktop\JavaStuff>del    *.class

C:\Users\GlaDOS\Desktop\JavaStuff>javac  Speed.java
Speed.java:43: error: illegal start of expression
                                                           " feet through air is
 " + if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)

     ^
Speed.java:43: error: ';' expected
                                                           " feet through air is
 " + if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)

       ^
Speed.java:43: error: not a statement
                                                           " feet through air is
 " + if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)

                         ^
Speed.java:43: error: ';' expected
                                                           " feet through air is
 " + if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)

                            ^
Speed.java:47: error: 'else' without 'if'

                                 else if (getSpeedInWater() > 0)

                                 ^
Speed.java:56: error: not a statement

                                   "error";)

                                   ^
Speed.java:56: error: illegal start of expression

                                   "error";)

                                           ^
7 errors

C:\Users\GlaDOS\Desktop\JavaStuff>java   Speed
Error: Could not find or load main class Speed
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Use multiple print statements, or a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a ternary operator `?:` instead of if / else

```
... " feet through air is " + (getSpeedInAir() > 0 ? : formatter.format(getSpeedInAir()) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many errors in your program.

1) You dont have an `if` statement. That is why you have got the error that `else without if`.

2) You last else is wrong:

```
else
 "error";)
```

You may proably try like this:

```
 if(getSpeedInAir() > 0)
 {
    System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is " +formatter.format(getSpeedInAir());
 }
 else if (getSpeedInWater() > 0)
 {
   System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is " + formatter.format(getSpeedInWater());
 }
else if (getSpeedInSteel() > 0)
{
  System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is " + formatter.format(getSpeedInSteel());
}
 else
   System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is "+ "error");
```

or more efficiently like this:-

```
String s;
if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)
{
    s= formatter.format(getSpeedInAir()).toString();
}
else if (getSpeedInWater() > 0)
{
    s= formatter.format(getSpeedInWater()).toString();
}
else if (getSpeedInSteel() > 0)
{
    s= formatter.format(getSpeedInSteel()).toString();
}
else
    s= "error";

System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is " + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

errror in this line

```
 "error";)
```

check this line
you might write something like this

```
System.out.println("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an if-statement inside the `System.out.println` like that.

You *could* do something with the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java), but for the sake of code readability, it's probably best to just declare a variable and concatenate like so:

```
String speed;
if (getSpeedInAir() > 0)
{
    speed = formatter.format(getSpeedInAir()).toString();
}
else if (getSpeedInWater() > 0)
{
    speed = formatter.format(getSpeedInWater()).toString();
}
else if (getSpeedInSteel() > 0)
{
    speed = formatter.format(getSpeedInSteel()).toString();
}
else
    speed = "error";

System.out.println("The time it takes the sound to travel " + distance +
                           " feet through air is " + speed);
```